# Error in showing alert dialog while clicking on a list view item

Tags: android, sqlite, android-alertdialog

Error in showing alert dialog while clicking on a list view item.

The code is given below.. this is a program  done in android sqlite.The data retrieved is shown in the list view   but the alert dialogue does not working properly for edit and delete.

please help me with the code......

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;

public class Display11 extends Activity {
    ListView listview;
    PopupWindow popup;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display1);

        listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        Intent in=getIntent();
        ArrayList<String> a=in.getStringArrayListExtra("Key");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dis=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,a);
        listview.setAdapter(dis);
        listview.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long rowId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ///public void OnItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long rowId){
                int itemposition = position;
                String itemValue = (String)listview.getItemAtPosition(position); 
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                AlertDialog.Builder alert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                /*LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
                View view1 =inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog,null);
                alert.setView(view1);*/
                //ad.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog, null));
                popup = new PopupWindow(getBaseContext());
                //popup.setContentView(alert_)
                alert.setMessage("Database Manager");

                alert.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                alert.setTitle("Terms of Service");

                alert.setPositiveButton("edit",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent positiveActivity=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),com.cerebtec.contactdb.PositiveActivity.class);
                    startActivity(positiveActivity);
                    }});

                alert.setNegativeButton("delete",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent negativeActivity=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),com.cerebtec.contactdb.NegativeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(negativeActivity);
                    }});
                //ad.setNeutralButton("Cancel",null);
                //ad.setCancelable(false);


                //AlertDialog alert=ad.create();
                //alert.setView(view1);
                alert.create();
                alert.show();
            }});
        }}
```

Comment: Does not showing alert dialogue

Comment: Added <!-- language: lang-cs -->

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this code:

`AlertDialog.Builder alert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());`

Application is the wrong context for UI stuff, you need the activity.  You need to use this:

`AlertDialog.Builder alert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(Display11.this);`